# propiedad no es un objeto php

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un echo de un objeto que es un string html, primero lo declare en un array y luego lo convertí en un objeto, le hago un `var_dump` y si sale pero al hacer el echo sale que la propiedad no es un objeto. pueden decirme que cometo mal? muchas gracias.

htmlclientes.php

```
 class HtmlClientes extends Clientes
 {

    protected $item;

    public function htmlItem($numer)
    {
      var_dump($numer);
      if ($numer % 6 == 0) {
        return $this->item = (object) array(
            'itemtop' => '<li class="flex flex-center-horizontal logo8">',
            'itembottom' => '</li>'
        );
      }
    }
 }
```

index.php

```
 <?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($clientes->getDatos() as $cliente){
    $cliente = (object) $cliente;
    $html = $clientes->htmlItem($i);
    var_dump($html);

    echo $html->itemtop;
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $rootUrl; ?>assets/images/img<?php echo $cliente->imagen; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cliente->nombre; ?>" />
 <?php
    echo $html->itembottom;
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

resultado var_dump

```
int(0)
 object(stdClass)#5 (2) {
   ["itemtop"]=>
     string(46) "<li class="flex flex-center-horizontal logo8">"
   ["itembottom"]=>
     string(5) "</li>"
 }
```

Comment: Hola! Puedes enviar el resultado del var_dump?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la función **htmlItem** debería retornar algún valor cuando la condición **if ($numer % 6 == 0)** no se cumple o bien validar si la variable $html no es nula, para entonces imprimir el resultado.

Ejemplo:

Función:

```
public function htmlItem($numer)
{
  var_dump($numer);
  if ($numer % 6 == 0) {
    return $this->item = (object) array(
        'itemtop' => '<li class="flex flex-center-horizontal logo8">',
        'itembottom' => '</li>'
    );
  }
  else return null;
}
```

Output:

```
 <?php
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($clientes->getDatos() as $cliente){
    $cliente = (object) $cliente;
    $html = $clientes->htmlItem($i);
    var_dump($html);

    if($html == null)
     continue;


    echo $html->itemtop;
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $rootUrl; ?>assets/images/img<?php echo $cliente->imagen; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cliente->nombre; ?>" />
 <?php
    echo $html->itembottom;
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: ah si era eso no me habia fijado, muchas gracias, pero return null no funciono entonces le puse el resutado con string en blanco.

Comment: Podrías confirmar si te ayudo mi respuesta, haciendo clic en la flecha hacia arriba. Fue un placer haberte ayudado.